# Checking parameter range at compile time

Tags: c#, range

I want to provide a function with an `int` parameter which must be within a predetermined range (say 10-20). I want this to take effect in *compile time*, and ideally in intellisense time - meaning that whenever the user  types `MyFunction(30)`, the `30` gets highlighted as a compilation error.

I realize the compiler can't know what the value is in compile time - for example `MyFunction(new Random().Next(100))`. Therefore, I should also check the param in runtime and `throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. However, I do want the compiler/IDE to highlight known-out-of-range-at-compile-time values.

I've tried:

```
void MyFunction([System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(10,20)] int param)
```

But that doesn't get enforced anywhere.

**In response to comments:**

- Enum: I want this to be a scalar value, but limited. For example, the param can be fileSize, and I want to limit it to 500,000 (=~500KB) - so when user calls `MyFunc(fileSize:1000000)`, he gets a compile error. Obviously, an enum doesn't fit this model.
- Constants-only: In most cases, my users will use constants - that's why this would have value for me.
- Resharper is not an option, because my users won't have it on their machines.
- [Roslyn Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix) looks interesting, but I'll need to find a way to distribute it to my users, and it's indeed overkill.
- I'm not sure how unit test would help - if my users calls with an out-of-range value, it's their bug, and my unit test will not catch it. I will catch the issue in runtime, of course.

Comment: Enum, maybe? You will have a bit of a hard time naming fields, though.

Comment: Why do you want that? This smells strange to be honest. Ideally you want to create a model that only fits valid values so you don't have this kind of issues.

Comment: You could do this using Roslyn diagnostics (compile-time user-defined warnings).

Comment: @AntonGogolev unfortunately you can pass any int (by default its int) as enum type value

Comment: @Jonathan compiler will help you with hard-coded values. But will you use  only hard-coded values with your function. Usually value of parameter is unknown until runtime

Comment: I think you can use some ReSharper code-contracts for that. But anyway I doubt this is a good scenario as it will help you only with hard-coded values which you hopefully avoid in your code.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - re: passing int, only with an explicit cast (except for literal 0). Once you're doing explicit casts, you're effectively overruling the compiler anyway.

Comment: Languages like Pascal have ranged integer types where such a thing could be possible; C# doesn't, and the compiler can't be extended on the fly within a program to respect attributes like this. You can, of course, build extensions for it (with Roslyn or the aforementioned Resharper), but I expect this would be far more trouble than it's actually worth. A mistake in a constant at compile time is not common enough to build all this infrastructure for; just have the runtime check and unit tests take care of it.

Comment: Use unit tests for this kind of restrictions. You can validate input value and throw exception if value is out of range. In unit tests you will create a tests for invalid values with expected exception - The tests will be perfect "documentation" for consumers of your method.

Comment: Responded to comments in an edit. @Jeroen: Resharper or Roslyn is the right answer - put it in an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: [Code Contracts](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/code-contracts/) *should* have been the answer, were it not for the fact that Microsoft seem to be ignoring them now.